# What is the difference between %f and %F in C?

Tags: c

Started to learn C and stacked with one question. 
At the chapter about the console output describes the conversion specifications and two of them are %f and %F. I tried to figure out what's the difference between them and wrote a simple C script given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float num = 123.456;
    printf("First float: %f \n", num);
    printf("Second float: %F \n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
First float: 123.456001
Second float: 123.456001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (**7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**)

> A `double` argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the
>   styles [-]inf or [-]infinity — which style is implementation-defined.
>   A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles
>   [-]nan or [-]nan(n-char-sequence) — which style, and the meaning of
>   any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The `F` conversion
>   specifier produces `INF`, `INFINITY`, or `NAN` instead of `inf`, `infinity`, or
>   `nan`, respectively.